# Error: In KmsWrappedCryptoKey, 'crypto_key_name': must be from location 'global'

Tags: google-cloud-dlp

I am trying to create a de-identification template using DLP from console in GCP.Using dataflow template to pick the csv data from gcs and load into BigQuert.

When I am creating the Cryptokey in global location and de-identification template also in Global it is  successfully encrypting the csv data and loading in BigQuery. For other combination of Crypto key and De-identification template always getting error in dataflow.as "PERMISSION_DENIED: Not authorized to access requested deidentify template."

Also when creating the template in Global and key using from other location than Global I am getting the below error at the time of creating the template itself.
Error:  In KmsWrappedCryptoKey, 'crypto_key_name': must be from location 'global'.

My question is can't we use crpto key and template created in any region other than Global?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your template and key need to be co-located in the same region.

Comment: Thanks for the response but when I am trying with Key in us-east1 and also the template in US-east1 I am getting the permission error. But when giving both as Global working without error.Is it the limitaion that we need to go only for Global for both(key and template)?

Comment: And the de-id content call is in us-east1 too? Your repro steps are a bit confusing, can you state a bit more precisely the request that is failing?

Comment: Yes everything in same region.

Comment: Can you give a sample of your API call for creating the DeidentifyTemplate? This is the API you should be using: https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.deidentifyTemplates/create Make sure to pass `/locations/us-east1` as parent, and make sure the template resource name contains `/locations/us-east1/` in it after it is created.